# Sending mail through PHP from a Flash application

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, email

I am building a flash website and I want contact information sent to my gmail address.

The Lynda.com tutorial I am using says I need to "enter the php address."  What is that and how do I do it?

This is my code edited

```
if (thename.text == "" || theemail.text == "" || thephone.text == "" || themessage.text =="") {
    thefeedback.text = "*Please fill out all fields";
} else {
    var allvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables()
    allvars.name = thename.text;
    allvars.email = theemail.text;
    allvars.phone = thephone.text;
    allvars.message = themessage.text;

    // Send info to a new request
    var mailAddress:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://whatever goes here.php");
    mailAddress.data = allvars;
    mailAddress.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sendToURL(mailAddress);
    thefeedback.text = "Thank You";
    thename.text = "";
    theemail.text = "";
    thephone.text = "";
    themessage.text = "";
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include **the code your Flash application is using to send data to your PHP script**?  With that information, we can show you how to send mail using PHP.

Comment: thanks for that snippet, but we need more.  What's inside `allvars`, please?  That's the data that will be sent to the script, and we'll need to know what's in there to help you compose your mail.

Comment: From your comments it appears that you have your actionscript code as well as your php code, you just don't know how they work together? You will need to put your php script on a server and then point your URLRequest at it eg.  var mailAddress:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http:// mydomain.com/mySimpleSampleMessage.php");

Answer (score 0):

Presumably they mean "A URL that resolves to the PHP script that they taught you to write", but "php address" is not a standard term.

Comment: I think that is what they mean.  do you know how to figure that out?

Comment: Generally speaking — the same way as you map any other URL onto a file on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

When you press submit on any form it is taking that information (first name, last name, body text, etc) and then it needs to be sent somewhere so that it can be given to gmail or anther email service as an actual email.

Now PHP on a server can take the information, turn it into an email, and send it from you to them.

You can do this by using POST and the URL is to a PHP script that lives somewhere.

Now that script needs set up, you can learn how [HERE](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm)

Good luck friend!

Comment: this is the code I have.  still not sure how to set up.                                                                    var mailAddress:URLRequest = new URLRequest("this is where the .php is supposed to go");
 mailAddress.data = allvars;
 mailAddress.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 sendToURL(mailAddress);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend PHP to use PHP functions from Flash.

This tutorial is pretty good: http://www.flepstudio.org/forum/tutorials/3421-actionscript-3-0-zend-amf.html