# Send Input Text Variable to Email - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, email

Is there any way I can send the string of an input text component to an email?

Comment: what server do you want to use? php? nodejs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437970/sending-mail-through-php-from-a-flash-application

Answer (score 0):

Use information from the following to send an email with php:

[Sending mail through PHP from a Flash application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437970/sending-mail-through-php-from-a-flash-application)

To get the string of an input text field use:

```
var inputString:String = myInputTextField.text;
```